# How to test the paid version of your chrome extension without paying?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, payment

I have a Chrome Extension which supports both a free and a paid version. I would like to obtain the full version of my app without paying for it. Is that possible?

Or maybe I can add something to the manifest file or the JavaScript? I tried to find something on this topic, but I only found one article which was outdated.

Comment: how much is the cost, i do not believe that would be more than 10$, buy it.. or if ya don't want to find some way to steal it :D

Comment: Lol, I guess I will buy it anyways. Now I receive this error while paying: "An unexpected error has occurred. Try again later."

Comment: the official guide to adding store payments clearly explains how to use the sandbox store.

Comment: If the paid functionality is present in the source code but capped through a payment check, you can copy the source code of the extension to a different folder (except the _metadata folder), modify the source to override the payment check, and load unpacked extension from that copy.

Comment: Just for future reference: I cannot buy my own chrome extension with the same Google Account as my developer account. I can however buy it with another Google Account.

Comment: @ZigMandel In which guide did you find your information?

Comment: sorry for my last comment which I can no longer edit. there used to be a page about using a sandbox store but cant find it now. will post if i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

This answer works better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795076/5437864

<strike>I used the token generated by `getAuthToken()` to identify my own developer account in code to promote it to the full version.</strike>

> (Read more about getAuthToken() here:
>   https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method)