# How to get the unique user ID in a chrome extension using OAuth?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I am using the `identity` permission in my manifest file and in my JavaScript code I use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function( token )` to get the use identification token.

How do I get the unique user ID or e-mail address? Preferrably without adding new permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) to get both the email address and a unique id. You will need to add the `identity.email` permission (in addition to `identity`). It does not require an OAuth2 token (or even a network connection).

Here is a minimal extension that prints this information to the console of a background page:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,

  "name" : "Identity Test",
  "version" : "0.1",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "identity.email"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(userInfo));
});
```

---

You could instead get user info by calling the Google API with the OAuth2 token. I believe you will need to set both the `profile` and `email` scopes. If you use the [Google API Client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/), you can call [`gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/). This more strictly satisfies the letter of your question, which specifies using OAuth and prefers not adding permissions, but I would guess that `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo()` is what you're really looking for.

Comment: Note: This works only if the user is signed into a profile inside of chrome, otherwise the response would be empty. But still +1, as this is closest to what is possible of a true unique ID inside Chrome.

Comment: U can add a check for if the is = ""

Answer (score 0):

Without additional permissions, it will depend on the [oauth2 scopes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#update_manifest) you declared in your manifest.json file.

For example, if you declared any Google Drive scope, you can use Google Drive's About GET method (see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get)) to retrieve the user's id and e-mail, among [other data](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource-representations).